# Access div id from Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have set up a bunch of divs that open a popover on hover.
When clicked, those buttons open a bootstrap modal which content depends on the id of the launching div. Everything is fine so far.

But now I would like to make the popover itself clickable and be able to launch the modal. That's ok but I can't display the modal content since my jQuery script can't access the launching div id.

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

The launching div:

```
<a class="dev_grid-cell">
<div id="crl0_trl2" class="wrapper" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Content of the popover">
</div>
</a>
```

The javascript

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".popover", function (){
  $("#MMmodal").modal("show");
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover("hide");
});

// So far, it's ok: the modal launches.

jQuery(document).on("click", ".popover", function (){
  var divID = this.id; // —> Here is the problem
  var fields = divID.split("_");
  var crl = "#"+fields[0];
  var trl = "#"+fields[1];
  $("#crl").children().hide();
  $("#trl").children().hide();
  $(trl).css("display","block");
  $(crl).css("display","block");
  alert(divID); // —> returns "Undefined" or something like "popover457812"
});
```

Comment: You can try using the `shown.bs.popover` event to include some data on the popover telling it who created it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. You're right, using $(this) is going to refer to the document. But eventObj.target refers to the actual clicked element.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".popover", function (eventObj){
  var divID = eventObj.target.id; // —> This may fix the problem
  var fields = divID.split("_");
  var crl = "#"+fields[0];
  var trl = "#"+fields[1];
  $("#crl").children().hide();
  $("#trl").children().hide();
  $(trl).css("display","block");
  $(crl).css("display","block");
  alert(divID);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. :-( The alert doesn't even show up.